# Scheduled Task gets removed upon reboot

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to make a scheduled task for a small software I had written for a friend,
I'm using
`Schtasks /create /SC MINUTE /MO 30 /tn JoesInventoryReader /tr C:\joes.exe /RL HIGHEST`
But for some reason, whenever we reboot the computer, this task is removed.
I was reading all of `Schtasks` parameters and none mentioned anything related to automatic removal.

Help? I've been trying to fix that for over an hour.
Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your task is triggered *once* and then runs repeatedly.

If you want to execute the program regularly, you should use `/SC DAILY` (or weekly, monthly) or `/SC ONLOGON`.

Use `/RI` to define the repetition and `/DU` to define the length of the repetition:

```
Schtasks /create /SC DAILY /RI 30 /DU 24:00 /tn JoesInventoryReader /tr C:\joes.exe /RL HIGHEST
```

Comment: That would make my code run once every 30 days.... A simple test in batch would've let you know that as well. The `/SC` sets a frequency, then `/MO` sets the modifier- 30 in my case.

Thanks anyways...............

Comment: @CodingCode: I didn't say you should keep /MO. You need to use parameters that match /SC DAILY. I've edited the answr

Comment: I see, thanks. Was thinking it's another spa comment, I'm terribly sorry.
One thing I'll add to your updated answer though is `/ST`(start time) as when it's not set, it defaults to current hour-
`Schtasks /create /SC DAILY /RI 10 /ST 00:00 /DU 24:00 /tn JoesInventoryReader /tr C:\joes.exe`

For viewers:
The following line would be creating a task that runs every (RI) 10 minutes, between (`/ST to /DU) 00:00 to 24:00(00 the next day), running C:\joes.exe, And named `JoesInventoryReader` In windows'es task list =]